# hibernate mapping - just like instagram follower and following

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, entity-relationship

I'm trying to build mini app where I'm replicating a feature of Instagram. Where a user can have multiple follower and multiple following.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<User> following;

    @OneToMany
    private List<User> followers;
}
```

I'm expecting that the hibernate will create  a similar table ("following") just like this and get mapped to it itself. I have tried using @JoinTable but it didn't worked out well for me. Most probably I've not did it in the correct way. Because the @JoinTable created two different table for me one to track follower and another one to track following.

```
@Entity
public class Following {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_id")
    private User source; // followed by

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
    private User target; // following to
}
```

And Following class is not necessarily to have in the code its just I'm thinking its good to have. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

you can use Recursive relationship since following and follower is type of user.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<User> following;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<User> followers;
}
```